# Падение элемента div при нажатии на кнопки

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня такой код:

```js
var checkAnimation = 0;
var checkJump = true;

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
     if (checkAnimation == 0) {
         var object = document.querySelector('.object').offsetLeft;
   xn = object + 50;
   document.querySelector('.object').style.left = xn + 'px';
   document.querySelector('.object').style.background = 'url(img/move1.png) no-repeat';
   document.querySelector('.object').style.transform = 'scale(1, 1)';
   checkAnimation++;
  } else if (checkAnimation == 1) {
         var object = document.querySelector('.object').offsetLeft;
   xn = object + 50;
   document.querySelector('.object').style.left = xn + 'px';
   document.querySelector('.object').style.background = 'url(img/move2.png) no-repeat';
   document.querySelector('.object').style.transform = 'scale(1, 1)';
   checkAnimation--;
  }
    }

    else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
     if (checkAnimation == 0) {
         var object = document.querySelector('.object').offsetLeft;
   xn = object - 50;
   document.querySelector('.object').style.left = xn + 'px';
   document.querySelector('.object').style.background = 'url(img/move1.png) no-repeat';
   document.querySelector('.object').style.transform = 'scale(-1, 1)';
   checkAnimation++;
  } else if (checkAnimation == 1) {
         var object = document.querySelector('.object').offsetLeft;
   xn = object - 50;
   document.querySelector('.object').style.left = xn + 'px';
   document.querySelector('.object').style.background = 'url(img/move2.png) no-repeat';
   document.querySelector('.object').style.transform = 'scale(-1, 1)';
   checkAnimation--;
  }
    }

    else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
     // Падение элемента
 }
}
```

```css
* {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.object {
 border: 1px solid black;
 width: 80px;
 height: 110px;
 background: url(img/start.png) no-repeat;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 130px;
 left: 20px;
 transition: left .1s linear;
}

.earth {
 width: 100%;
 height: 130px;
 background: lightgreen;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="object">

 </div>

 <div class="earth">
  
 </div>

 <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

При нажатии на клавишу с кодом 38 (стрелка вверх) объект должен подлетать вверх и падать, но у меня получается только делать чтобы он подлетал вверх. Как можно сделать падение?

Answer (score 0):

https://jsbin.com/xosoviqece/edit?js,output

```
var checkAnimation = 0;
var checkJump = true;
var minBottom = null;

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        if (checkAnimation == 0) {
            var object = document.querySelector('.object').offsetLeft;
            xn = object + 50;
            document.querySelector('.object').style.left = xn + 'px';
            document.querySelector('.object').style.background = 'url(img/move1.png) no-repeat';
            document.querySelector('.object').style.transform = 'scale(1, 1)';
            checkAnimation++;
        } else if (checkAnimation == 1) {
            var object = document.querySelector('.object').offsetLeft;
            xn = object + 50;
            document.querySelector('.object').style.left = xn + 'px';
            document.querySelector('.object').style.background = 'url(img/move2.png) no-repeat';
            document.querySelector('.object').style.transform = 'scale(1, 1)';
            checkAnimation--;
        }
    }

    else if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        if (checkAnimation == 0) {
            var object = document.querySelector('.object').offsetLeft;
            xn = object - 50;
            document.querySelector('.object').style.left = xn + 'px';
            document.querySelector('.object').style.background = 'url(img/move1.png) no-repeat';
            document.querySelector('.object').style.transform = 'scale(-1, 1)';
            checkAnimation++;
        } else if (checkAnimation == 1) {
            var object = document.querySelector('.object').offsetLeft;
            xn = object - 50;
            document.querySelector('.object').style.left = xn + 'px';
            document.querySelector('.object').style.background = 'url(img/move2.png) no-repeat';
            document.querySelector('.object').style.transform = 'scale(-1, 1)';
            checkAnimation--;
        }
    }

    else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
            var obj = document.querySelector('.object');
            var rect = obj.getBoundingClientRect();
            var object = window.innerHeight - (rect.y + rect.height);
            if (minBottom === null) {
              minBottom = object;
            } else {
              minBottom = Math.min(minBottom, object);
            }
            xn = object + 250;
            document.querySelector('.object').style.bottom = xn + 'px';
            timeout = setTimeout(() => {
              document.querySelector('.object').style.bottom = minBottom + 'px';
            }, 100);
    }
}
```

Но, когда хочешь анимировать что-либо на сайтах, то используй лучше CSS Transitions или готовые решения (пример https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/).

Comment: а вот проблема, я поставил transition и теперь когда много раз нажимаю стрелку вверх он всё выше и выше поднимается, не подскажите как это исправить?